# Why is simplexml_load_file not returning a simple array in my PHP script?

Tags: php, arrays, api, simplexml

I'm using the `simplexml_load_file` command to parse data from an api to the MMO I subscribe to make a tool to get the current guild rooster.  The raw xml that is returned from the api looks like:

```
<apiresponse>
    <guild name="Seekers of Forgotten Pasts" world="Cannith" memberCount="1312">
        <characters>
            <character name="Nethershadow" surname="" rank_level="5" rank_name="Officer" race="Halfling" gender="m" alignment="True Neutral">
            <classes>
                <class name="Ranger" level="2"/>
                <class name="Rogue" level="8"/>
            </classes>
        </character>
        <character name="..." surname="..." rank_level="..." rank_name="..." race="..." gender="..." alignment="...">
            ...
        </character>
        <character name="Calomel" surname="" rank_level="10" rank_name="Member" race="Drow Elf" gender="m" alignment="Lawful Good">
            <classes>
                <class name="Paladin" level="5"/>
            </classes>
        </character>
    </guild>
<cache_info cached_until_gmt="2013-01-05 19:23"/>
</apiresponse>
```

Now, when I plug in my php to retrieve the list of names, as such:

```
<?php
    $names = array();
    $xmlGuild = simplexml_load_file($DataDDO_api_urlFullGuildSearch);
    $characters = $xmlGuild->guild->characters->character;
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($characters); $i++) {
        $names[] = $characters[$i]->attributes()->name;
    }
    echo "\n\nTotal members: " . count($names) . "\n\n<pre>\n";
    print_r($names);
    echo "</pre>\n";
?>
```

I get as a result:

```
Total members: 1312

Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => Nethershadow
        )
    [...] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => ...
        )
    [1311] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => Calomel
        )
)
```

Instead of what I am expecting of:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Nethershadow
    [...] => ...
    [1311] => Calomel
)
```

Why is this?

Comment: As an aside, could it be that you mean `count()` instead of `sizeof()`? Also, this is better solved with a `foreach` loop.

Comment: I tried the loop section as `foreach ($characters as $character) {$names[] = $character->attributes()->name;}` and got the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must cast SimpleXML objects to string if you want their text value.

```
<?php
    $names = array();
    $apiresponse = simplexml_load_file($DataDDO_api_urlFullGuildSearch);

    foreach ($apiresponse->guild->characters->character as $char) 
    {
        $names[] = (string)$char->attributes()->name;
    }

    echo "\n\nTotal members: " . count($names) . "\n\n<pre>\n";
    print_r($names);
    echo "</pre>\n";
?>
```

Comment: Perfect... so it is the `(string)` in `$names[] = (string)$char->attributes()->name;` that makes it work, just to be clear for other future instances?

Comment: @Shoe Yes. `$char->attributes()->name` returns a `SimpleXMLElement` object instance (see [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php)), not a string. You must make an explicit cast to string; this is the standard way to get the text value. Otherwise the whole object reference is stored in the `$names` array.